# Using loops for counting characters in string up to certain point

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function that counts the number of characters in a string up until it finds 0, and only counts up until then. For example, if we have a string "hello0bye", it will only count the number of characters in "hello".

I know there is strlen, but I'm unsure of how to implement the 0 in this. I'm trying to write this using either a for loop or a while loop. Thank you!

Comment: Test each character until you find `'0'`.

Comment: `strchr(str,'0') - str`. this works if `0` is in the string!

Comment: `man strcspn`  "... it computes the string array index of
     the first character of s which is also in charset, else the index of the first null character."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> int count_char_until_zero(char *str);
>
> int main() {
>
>   int i = count_char_until_zero("kaja0pia");
>   printf("Char num until zero: %d\n", i);
>   return 0;
> }
>
> int count_char_until_zero(char *str) {
>   int i = 0;
>   while(str[i] != '0') {
>       i++;
>   }
>   return i; 
> }
> ```